# How to optimize a function with multiple return values in R

Tags: r

I'm creating an function to be minimized, basically a function of `x1`, returning value `cmc`. BTW I like it return some intermediate value `w` for later use. I just learnt to create functions return multiple values, you have to make a list, or setClass (which I'm not very clear about, so I did not use it). The executable code is

```
t1=1; t2=0.6; x2=1;
c=c(0,1)
f<-function(x) c(x/(t2+x),-t1*x/(t2+x)^2)
phi_c<-function(x1){
  X=rbind(f(x1),f(x2))
  v=solve(X%*%t(X))%*%X%*%c
  w=abs(v)/sum(abs(v))
  cmc=t(c)%*%solve(t(X)%*%diag(c(w))%*%X)%*%c
  return(list(cmc,w))
}
phi_c(0.5)
```

The output is not very decent but acceptable. The problem is I cannot optimize a function with such output. So now I am doing

```
t1=1; t2=0.6; x2=1;
c=c(0,1)
f<-function(x) c(x/(t2+x),-t1*x/(t2+x)^2)
phi_c<-function(x1){
  X=rbind(f(x1),f(x2))
  v=solve(X%*%t(X))%*%X%*%c
  w=abs(v)/sum(abs(v))
  cmc=t(c)%*%solve(t(X)%*%diag(c(w))%*%X)%*%c
}
x1=optimize(phi_c,c(0,x2))$min
X=rbind(f(x1),f(x2))
v=solve(X%*%t(X))%*%X%*%c
w=abs(v)/sum(abs(v))
```

very redundant. It's ok when the problem is simple as this one, but obviously not good when things become complicated. Is there a way to create a function with multiple return values and allows you to set a prime value to be optimized? I remember some base functions are like that, give you various output but you can still work with a prime value.
Thanks.

Comment: Put w in an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap this function in a different function that only returns the intended output. such as

```
t1=1; t2=0.6; x2=1;
c=c(0,1)
f<-function(x) c(x/(t2+x),-t1*x/(t2+x)^2)
phi_c<-function(x1){
  X=rbind(f(x1),f(x2))
  v=solve(X%*%t(X))%*%X%*%c
  w=abs(v)/sum(abs(v))
  cmc=t(c)%*%solve(t(X)%*%diag(c(w))%*%X)%*%c
  return(list(cmc,w))
}
> optimize(function(x) phi_c(x)[[1]], lower = 0, upper = 5)
$minimum
[1] 4.999922

$objective
         [,1]
[1,] 37.12268
```